# Wash sale with options and stocks

Tags: united-states, taxes, wash-sale

Let's say the following happens within 30 days.

1. Buy 10 shares for total of $100.
2. Buy a call option
3. Sell the call option for a $1000 loss.
4. Buy 1 share for $10.

Does buying back that 1 share fall under the wash sale rule and prevent me from writing off any of that $1000?
Thanks!